# In scrapyd, how to pass FEED_URI value through schedule api

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapyd

I want scrapyd to run my spider on cloud, for which I want to pass the value of FEED_URI as a parameter in scrapyd command.

Currently I am using following configuration in custom setting to store the output on s3.

```
custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT':'csv',
        'FEED_URI':'s3://my_bucket/%s'%('OP_FILE')
        }
```

However I would like to pass the value for the custom_setting through the

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=link -d spider=link -d OP_FILE="output_link.csv"
```

Apparently custom_setting value can't be set inside '**init**' method of the link spider class.

What can I do to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FEEDS setting](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEEDS) (new in scrapy version 2.1) like this in your command:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=link -d spider=link -d 'setting=FEEDS={"output_link.csv":{"format": "csv"}}'
```

**`FEED_FORMAT` and `FEED_URI` have been deprecated**. If you are using an old scrapy version and must use these settings, you would pass them like this:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=link -d spider=link -d setting=FEED_URI=output_link.csv -d setting=FEED_FORMAT=csv
```